# On browser close kill devise session

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I know previously there are questions related to my topic, i have read it but didn't help.

I have placed the below code in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
config.skip_session_storage = [:disabled]
```

So normal login is happening and the session maintained till the browser is open, and when the browser is closed session is killed.It asks for new login in new browser window.

I woul like to know  what is happening, will there be any problem in keeping skip_session_storage disabled. In future i'll use payment gateway and will it affect it?

Answer (score 0):

I've face with the same issue. To keep user sign in after browser close you need to do these things like. Include in your model :rememberable (it should include by default)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

your session controller should looks like

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
 include Devise::Controllers::Rememberable

 def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  #add remember me to remember user
  remember_me resource
  respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 end
end
```

as you can see there method remember me which basically do the job. Here point to official documentation about this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable

How all these stuff works? Basically when you call remember_me on user side set up a cookie you should saw something like remember_user_token (i assume that your authentication model is user) in Chrome/Firefox/Safari inspector. Then everything should works hope it helps.